# Makefile to compile multiple mex functions

Tags: c++, matlab, makefile

I have the following makefile which I run to compile the mex functions:

```
    SRC:=$(wildcard ./source/*.c)
    all: $(SRC)
            for file in $^ ; do \
            mex -outdir matlab/ -output $@ $$file CC=mpicc CXX=mpicxx COPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG" LDOPTIMFLAGS="-O2"; \
            done
    .PHONY: clean
    clean:
            rm ./matlab/*.mexa64
```

The code compiles all the files even if I modified one.
I had created a makefile thinking only the modified files would be compiled and not all of them.
I am presently unable to find a way to do this. Compiling all files for the slightest change made to one of them is highly time consuming as I have around 50 files to compile.
Any help is appreciated.
Let me know if I am being unclear anywhere.

Comment: Have you read any makefile tutorials? Also, are you using `/matlab` instead of `./matlab` and the same for `/source` on purpose? I mean, if that's really your code, it's working properly: you're just not deleting what you're trying to delete.

Comment: Is there a simple correlation between source files and mex files? That is, if you start with `foo.c`, do you get `foo.mexa64` and nothing else?

Comment: Sorry..  I edited it..

Comment: @Beta Yes that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working. Thanks to @Beta for your input. I used the $? as you suggested and modified the code to the following fully functional one:

```
SRC:=$(wildcard ./source/*.c)
all: $(SRC)
    for file in $? ; do \
    mex -outdir matlab/ $$file CC=mpicc CXX=mpicxx COPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG" LDOPTIMFLAGS="-O2"; \
    done
    touch all;
```

The $? gets the list of all files that are modified.
Than $@ compiles them one by one.
Than touch all marks them all as updated.
Works perfectly.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You are rebuilding all of the mex files because 1) you are cycling through the `$^` variable, which contains *all* of the prerequisites, not just the ones that have changed since the target was last modified, and 2) you are using a phony target, `all`, so Make keeps executing the rule, trying to rebuild that file.

You could solve the first problem by changing a single character; the `$?` variable contains a list of prerequisites that are newer than the target. But that wouldn't solve the second problem. A better approach is to dispense with the `for` loop and use Make itself:

```
SRC := $(wildcard ./source/*.c)
TARGS := $(patsubst ./source/*.c, ./matlab/*.mexa64, $(SRC))

all: $(TARGS)

./matlab/%.mexa64: ./source/%.c
    mex -outdir matlab/ -output all $*.mexa64 CC=mpicc CXX=mpicxx COPTIMFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG" LDOPTIMFLAGS="-O2";
```

Comment: what does:  
'TARGS := $(patsubst ./source/*.c, ./matlab/*.mexa64, $(SRC))'
do?

Comment: @Pundit: The [`patsubst`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) converts the SRC list from `./source/foo.c ./source/bar.c ...` to `./matlab/foo.mexa64 ./matlab/bar.mexa64 ...`, and the "TARGS :=" puts the new list into a variable called `TARGS`.